# Save error: Loop variable must be of type LIST<String>

Tags: list

i am getting an error given below while i trying to iterate a List of String lists. I am thinking that i missed something very simple but did not able to move beyond this issue. Please clarify.

> Save error: Loop variable must be of type LIST

```
List<List<String>> lstResp = new List<List<String>> {};
lstResp = Utility.ParseMultipleResponse(ret);
for(List<List<String>> n: lstResp) { //error line 
   for(List<String> l: n) {
     //-------some code here-------------
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hopefully these names help explain what is going on:

```
List<List<String>> listOfListOfString = Utility.ParseMultipleResponse(ret);
for (List<String> listOfString : listOfListOfString) {
    for (String str : listOfString) {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Each for loop iterates over a list, so the type of the for loop variable is "one list less" in each case.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I understood the issue now based on your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your list is type of `List<String>`. So an element is type of that. Your `for` loop should be something like,

```
for(List<String> firstList: lstResp) { 
   for(String singleString : firstList){
   // Some code
   }
}
```